# Loading multiple libraries in codeigniter using array(). First library works, but second doesn't

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm loading two controllers from within my main controller and only the first one loads.

```
class App extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->library(array('../controllers/effects', 
                             '../controllers/ingredients'));
        $data['ingredients'] = $this->ingredients->get_all();
        $data['effects'] = $this->effects->get_all();

        $this->load->view('header');      
        $this->load->view('main', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }
}
```

I'm getting the error `Message: Undefined property: App::$ingredients`. If I switch the two path strings like this

```
$this->load->library(array('../controllers/ingredients', '../controllers/effects'));
```

then it says effects is undefined so it looks like it always loads the first controller but not the second. I tried autoloading them as well but I got an error like "nested function limit exceeded" or something. What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to put your libraries in the `libraries` folder instead of the `controllers` folder?  Also, just the library name should be enough, no need for the path.

Answer (score 3):

put your library file in `libraries` folder inside `CI`

Now you can load your library in controller

```
$this->load->library('library_name');
```

to load multiple libraries in array

```
$this->load->library(array('library_name_1', 'library_name_2'));
```

or you can Auto-load Libraries in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('library_name_1', 'library_name_2');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow what the manual says about [libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/libraries.html).

You should put the library file on library folder and the load the library with

> $this->load->library('name');